# Carrierwave attachment issue

Tags: carrierwave

Total noob here. I'm trying to build a blog app. Paperclip wasn't working, something to do with compatibility. So I switched to carrierwave. However, I'm still unable to get any images into my database.

pardon the mess
Here is my article class where I want to mount the uploader

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :attachment, :attachment_cache, :remove_attachment

mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
serialize :attachments, JSON

has_many :comments
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
#has_attached_file :image





end
```

And the helper for it where the params are

```
    module ArticlesHelper

def article_params

params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, :attachment, :attachment_cache, :remove_attachment )

    end

end
```

Here is the form

```
    <%= form_for(@article, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>


<ul>
<% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
<%end %>
</ul>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>

<p>

  <%= f.file_field :attachment, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.label :attachment, "Attach a New Image" %><br />
  <%= attachment_tag (@article.attachment_url) if @article.attachment? %>     
  <%= f.hidden_field :attachment_cache %>

</p>
<p>
    <label>
    <%= f.check_box :remove_attachment %>
    Remove image
    </label>    
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :tag_list %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</p>
```

Here is the uploader

```
    class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end



end
```

When I post an article with an attachment i get this sort of shpeal from the server:

```
    Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-26 14:56:00 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S1qbkO5mz4M0y8k9XyCPujbjOrSG9n6LmyNiTZBNFW8yJQ0j9H52sYYh4KyuMATOpsanO09/T7V9MyNV7sok9g==", "article"=>{"title"=>"yo", "body"=>"reverted on the file stuff", "attachment"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8ad5d64f90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170626-8487-1c1ts1q.jpg>, @original_filename="friedrich-nietzsche-watercolor-portrait1-fabrizio-cassetta.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"article[attachment][]\"; filename=\"friedrich-nietzsche-watercolor-portrait1-fabrizio-cassetta.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], "attachment_cache"=>"", "remove_attachment"=>"0", "tag_list"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
Unpermitted parameter: attachment
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "articles" ("title", "body", "created_at", "updated_at", "attachment") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "yo"], ["body", "reverted on the file stuff"], ["created_at", "2017-06-26 18:56:00.822167"], ["updated_at", "2017-06-26 18:56:00.822167"], ["attachment", nil]]
   (41.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles/52
Completed 302 Found in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 41.9ms)
```

Sometimes I can get the parameters matched up, if I don't try to add multiple attachments and remove the ability to do so, but the same thing happens to the image, it's never processed.

Any sort of point in the right direction would help, thanks in advance!